# Chrome Extension: What is the point of URL permissions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I thought adding `urls` to ones `permissions` in the `manifest.json` acted the same a the `matches` in `content scripts`, preventing the `background page` from running on any other websites. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058670/background-script-only-for-specific-domain-in-chrome-extension) informed me that is not the case and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096482/what-does-http-https-and-all-urls-mean-in-the-context-of-ch) claims that `permissions` allows the background page to interact with page code, what does that mean? I don't understand the point of `urls` in `permissions`

Comment: Various chrome.* API available in the background page can perform actions only on the permitted URLs. As for the first answer, it tells you what's already explained in the [architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch). I'm not sure what to add to the overview, it's already simple. As for the 2nd answer, ignore the `code` part which is the wrong term.

Comment: You appear to have assumed that the only way that one should be interacting with a URL is to inject a content script with a `content_scripts` directive in your *manifest.json*. That is limited thinking. There are may other ways to interact with pages, or other things for which you want access to specific URLs.

Comment: like doing AJAX without cross-domain issues.