# How to enable Chrome extension on this URLS?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How can you enable chrome extension on a specific web site? for an example

Activate or enable the chrome extension when you visit on a specific website say `www.test.com`
if the user browser through another than `www.test.com` then the icon should be deactivate or disable the chrome extension.
I have read about the [pageAction](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction)  and try to do the following:

manifest.js

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "PageAction Sample",
  "description": "PageAction Sample",
  "version": "0.0.1",

  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "32": "icon32.png"
    }
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": [ "background.js" ],
    "persistent": false
  },

  "permissions": [ "activeTab", "tabs" ]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.url) {
    if (changeInfo.url == 'test.com)) {
      chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
    } else {
      chrome.pageAction.hide(tabId);
    }
  }
});

chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
    file: "login.js"
  });
});
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Login Form</h3>
    <form>
      Username: <input id="username" type="text" name="username"> <br>
      Password: <input id="password" type="password" name="password"> <br>
      <input id="loginbutton" type="button" value="Login">
    </form>
    <script>
      document.getElementById('loginbutton').onclick = function(event) {
        var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
        setTimeout(function() {
          alert('Username: ' + username + ' and Password: ' + password);
        });
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Show the UI (popup.html) page only the url is test.com

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Background script only for specific domain in Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058670/background-script-only-for-specific-domain-in-chrome-extension)

Comment: thanks but the question yo posted does not resolve my issue and what it talking about persistent and event page but my question is more towards how can I solved the above issue which I raised

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here.

1. A [bug in Chrome](https://crbug.com/1127067) that always shows the extension's icon as active on all URLs.

   You'll have to manually change the icon via [chrome.pageAction.setIcon](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction#method-setIcon) in onUpdated event. A more ergonomic/proper solution would be to use [chrome.declarativeContent](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent) API (instead of onUpdated) with two actions: `SetIcon` and `ShowPageAction` (some [demos](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:declarativeContent)).

   Make a grayscale version of your main icon and specify it as the default icon in manifest.json, then use the above methods to set the normal icon on the matched site.
2. `popup.html` isn't specified anywhere. Add `"default_popup": "popup.html"` inside `page_action` section as shown in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction#manifest).
3. An [inline `<script>` doesn't work](/q/13591983/) in extensions by default so extract it to a separate popup.js file loaded as a standard tag like `<script src=popup.js></script>`.
4. chrome.pageAction.onClicked won't work with default_popup so move the contents of `onClicked` listener (executeScript block) into popup.js, right at the start of it or inside a click listener for some button.
5. Open the [correct devtools console](/a/38920982) to observe the errors and output instead of using `alert`.

Comment: do you have an example that you worked on similar scenario?

Comment: No. Try the official [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples).